# How to check errors cleanly in scala functionally?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Is there a way to avoid the nesting in the code below when checking for errors without simply chaining functions?

```
val a: Either[Value, Exception]
val b: Either[Value, Exception]
val c: Either[Value, Exception]

def combine(a: Either[Value, Exception], 
            b: Either[Value, Exception], 
            c: Either[Value, Exception]) = 
{
  a match {
    case Right(a) => Right(a)
    case Left(a)  => b match {
                       case Right(b) => Right(b)
                       case Left(b)  => c match {
                                          case Right(c) => Right(c)
                                          case Left(c)  => a + b + c
                                        }
                     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First: by convention (imported from Haskell, where it made more sense) errors are `Left` and correct values are `Right`.

Once we establish that convention: `.map` allows mapping Right value (it leaves `Left` value intact) while `.flatMap` allows you to turn `Right` value into either `Left` or `Right` - on `Right` it will continue composition, while `Left` will break the circuit.

Having:

```
val a: Either[Exception, Value]
val b: Either[Exception, Value]
val c: Either[Exception, Value]
```

you could write:

```
val abc: Either[Exception, Value] =
  a.flatMap { aValue =>
    b.flatMap { bValue =>
      c.map { cValue =>
        (aValue, bValue, cValue)
      }
    }
  }
```

which thanks to for comprehension can be written shorter as:

```
val abc = for {
  aValue <- a
  bValue <- b
  cValue <- c
} yield (aValue, bValue, cValue)
```

However, if you use `java.lang.Exception` as you error, then it would make more sense to use `Try` because `Try[A]` is very similar to `Either[Throwable, A]`, except that it also can catch exceptions thrown inside of it (and is shorter to write).

Answer (score 2):

Since `a`, `b`, and `c` are independent of each other [`Applicative`](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/applicative.html) approach can also avoid *"the pyramid of doom"*

```
import cats.implicits._
(a, b, c).mapN(_ + _ + _)
```

of if you wish to keep the happy value on the left side, consider swapping the sides like so

```
import cats.implicits._
(a.swap, b.swap, c.swap).mapN(_ + _ + _).swap
```